# Getting a runtime error 6 due to overflow

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am looping through all the controls in my form (mainly textbox and combobox) to display a calculated field directly when i click the button rating. It counts the number of y/n present in about 180 input boxes. But the code is throwing an error of overflow. Tried so many things like rounding up and all but nothing is working at the moment.

```
`Private sub comm_click()
Dim clt as control
For each clt in me.controls
If clt.ControlType= acTextBox or clt.ControlType= acComboBox then
total=0
sel=0
If clt.value=‘Y’ or clt.value=‘y’ then
sel=sel+1
End if
If clt.value=‘Y’ or clt.value=‘y’ or If clt.value=‘N’ or clt.value=‘n’
total=total+1
end if
clt.value=format(sel/total,4)
End if
Next`
```

Comment: Your code is not valid vba. `‘Y’` is not the standard string format, should be `"Y"`. The `Then` is missing for the 3rd `If`. Once corrected, we can see that if there is no Y, y, n, nor N your code tries to divide 0 per 0, hence the overflow. Check that total is not null before dividing.

Comment: By the way, your code do that division for each control, and resets sel and total variable for each textbox or combobox, so your algorithm is probably to be revised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely getting your overflow error when the control isn't a Y/N y/n

At the start you set everything to 0 so you'll need to place it up two lines and make sure you change the value in the third if-clause:

```
Private Sub comm_click()
    Dim clt as control
    Dim total As Long, sel As Long
    total=0
    sel=0
    For each clt in me.controls
        If clt.ControlType= acTextBox or clt.ControlType= acComboBox then
            If clt.value="Y" or clt.value="y" then
                sel=sel+1
            End if
            If clt.value="Y" or clt.value="y" or clt.value="N" or clt.value="n" Then
                total=total+1
            End if
        End if
    Next clt
    name.value=format(sel/total,4) 'edited in accordance to the comments
    'percentage was meant to be put in a separate textbox, not in every control
End Sub
```

I'm not sure why you'd want to adjust every Y/N y/n value but it's easy to adjust for a check at the end if your total is 0 to avoid the overflow.
Also adjusted your double quotations, declaring of variable and some typos.
Hope that's how  you had it in mind. Let me know if it isn't.

Comment: The syntax of the 2nd `If` statement (you copied it from OP) is wrong, it has an additional `If` and it misses the `Then`.

Comment: Well frick, fixing the indents in here made me lose track of it, thanks @FunThomas

Comment: If you put clt.value inside third if statement its not working anyways cause i want clt.value as a fixed number. I tried it using outside the for loop but its throwing “Object variable or with block variable not set”.

Comment: P.s. ignore my typos bcz it was due to my typing in mobile. I have declared total and sel above the for loop and have every “” quotes and then written

Comment: You want ALL of your controls with Y/N to have the sel/total of all said controls?

Comment: Nope, instead i have a textbox which is supposed to show the percentage of Y/y over total Y/y/N/n

Comment: So not all my controls have Ys andNs but there are about 180 of them so i cant type name of every single. Hence using this looping technique to iterate through all controls and just consider those controls which have only Ys or Ns

Comment: If it's a specific textbox, you'll have to give more information as to which it is because as you had it, you were putting it in every single control and I don't know which one needs the percentage.

Comment: Oops my bad. Thanks for pointing it out. I just had to put name.value = sel/total. 
Sorry im very new to this vba

Comment: Np, everyone starts somewhere :) Glad to have helped.